# How to change type from one owner to two different types of owners

Tags: database-design, normalization

I currently have (tables changed):

**User**

```
UserID uniqueidentifier,
CompanyID uniqueidentifier, (for future reference)
.. more unrelated fields

(PK: UserID)
```

**UserRating**

```
UserID uniqueidentifier,
MovieID uniqueidentifier,
RatingTypeID uniqueidentifier,
Rating tinyint

(PK: UserID, MovieID, RatingTypeID)
```

**RatingType**

```
RatingTypeID uniqueIdentifier,
Title varchar(25)

(PK: RatingTypeID)
```

The RatingType table contains "Favorite", "Need to Watch", etc.  So actual Rating value is how much they liked a Favorite, or how badly the want to watch a movie etc.

Now I introduce a new table:

**Company**

```
 CompanyID uniqueidentifier,
 .. more unrelated fields
```

The idea is that if a user becomes part of a company, due to requirements that cannot change, all the Ratings need to be Company ratings and not User Ratings.  I'm not a normalization guru, but for some reason creating another table (below) seems redundant, but maybe I'm thinking to much into it.

**CompanyRating**

```
CompanyID uniqueidentifier,
MovieID uniqueidentifier,
RatingTypeID uniqueidentifier,
Rating tinyint

(PK: CompanyID, MovieID, RatingTypeID)
```

This feels incorrect because it almost matches the rating table and if I need to do any averages it becomes more difficult to average across two tables.  Is there a better design for my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use an inheritance model.

**User**

```
UserID uniqueidentifier,
CompanyID uniqueidentifier, (for future reference)

(PK: UserID)
```

**Company**

```
CompanyID uniqueidentifier,
```

**Rating**

```
RatingID uniqueidentifier,
MovieID uniqueidentifier,
RatingTypeID uniqueidentifier,
Rating tinyint

(PK: RatingID)
```

**UserRating**

```
RatingID uniqueidentifier,
UserID uniqueidentifier,

(PK: RatingID, FK: UserRating_Rating)
```

**CompanyRating**

```
RatingID uniqueidentifier,
CompanyID uniqueidentifier,

(PK: RatingID, FK: CompanyRating_Rating)
```

**RatingType**

```
RatingTypeID uniqueIdentifier,
Title varchar(25)

(PK: RatingTypeID)
```

The Data model itself allows users to have individual rating while also being in a company with it's own rating, and that is ok as it might be needed in the future.  For now this allows me to aggregate values by MovieID and RatingTypeID, and with little work both UserRatingID and PartyRatingID.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you will benefit if you borrow party concept from Party-Role-Relationship, one of universal data models, which is capable of keeping all information you needed.

So you will have `party_type` table that will currently have 2 records, `person` and `organization`, one common `party` table that holds all people and companies (you may want to add 2 more tables , `person` and `company` that hold attributes specific to people and organizations respectively), and your `rating` will have a reference to `party`.